# similar to simplexml_load_file but for csv in php

Tags: php, xml, csv

When a client upload an xml file, the following piece of code  catch it "on the fly", and perform several operations **without actually saving** the file in the server (just a temp file I guess):

```
    if(isset($_POST['AddXmlElement'])) {
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($_FILES['NewRecordXml']['tmp_name']);
        foreach( $xml->records->record as $key1) {  
            //Do stuff;
        }
    }
```

I would like to do the same, but with a csv file. Is there an instruction like "simplecsv_load_file" that can be used?

Comment: It would be nice to know the reason for the downvote. It seems to me that this is a proper fair question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `fopen()` to open a read connection on the csv upload:

```
$handle = fopen($_FILES["csvfile"]["tmp_name"], "r");

// LOOP ITERATES THROUGH ALL ROWS OF CSV FILE
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    echo $data[0];            // FIRST COMMA-SEPARATED CONTENT
    echo $data[1];            // SECOND COMMA-SEPARATED CONTENT
    ...
}

fclose($handle);
```